# synchronize a mysql database and a folder

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, filesystems

How can I synchronize a database , in which I store metadata (filename , path, size ,type...), and a folder on my file system ?? I need this for my webapplication (spring mvc) that allows users to see their files on a server . for example if I add or remove manually some files on the server (ubuntu server) I want the database to be updated adding or deleting  rows . Should my application rescan the folder , delete all table's rows and insert the actual list of files in the database each time the user refresh the page ? In this case , each time the user refresh the page I have to revise the table even if I didn't modify the folder's content. Is it possible to make the database listen to the folder and automatically update rows ? Help me please

Answer (score 0):

There is needed functionality to periodically examine the timestamp of the folder and its subfolders if any to detect recent changes and then update the database if there were any. A fairly simple script could do that and be scheduled from cron or run as a daemon. It is also possible to implement a stored procedure to do that and schedule it as a repeating event.  If necessary it could call an external executable with sys_exec. See http://www.mysqludf.org/ for sys_exec sources and other UDFs. Information about creating events in MySQL is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html.

To help with detecting changes in a folder I wrote an utility called tfind that has a 1 second resolution. Its usage can be printed by running 'tfind --help', for example 'tfind --mtime 30 folder' prints the names of all files in folder with modification time less than 30 seconds old. tfind is written in perl and will work on all Linux systems with perl installed in /usr/bin/perl. If perl is installed somewhere else just update the first line with the correct pathname. The script can also be modified to print only '1' if it finds any recently modified files/folders. It prints nothing if there are no such files/folders. tfind is available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zalacer/projects-tn/master/Perl/tfind?raw=TRUE.

Comment: thank you, I'll see that :) But while looking for how I can do it in java  I found  the Package **java.nio..**  that defines interfaces and classes for the Java virtual machine to access files, file attributes, and file systems. I think I can watch the directory and update the database if an event occurs. what do you think ?

Comment: That should work well. Looks like Oracle has complete code for it at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java.